# Can't set custom validator messages in Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I just can't figure it out how to set custom validator messages in Zend_Form object. Here is an example code.

```
$this->addElement('password', 'password', array(
        'label'      => 'Password',
        'decorators' => array('ViewHelper'),
        'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
        'validators' => array(
            array('Digits', false, array('messages' => array('notDigits' => 'Only digits are allowed here')))
        ),
        'required'   => true

    ));
```

When I try to validate the form entering invalid data  a message saying  "notDigits" appear.  I tried to change 'notDigits'  to  Zend_Validate_Digits::NOT_DIGITS, but it still doesn't work as expected.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my error. I was recieving the 'notDigits' message, because in the controller I used $form->getErrors() method instead of  $form->getMessages().  The first one returns only the error codes, without the messages.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for setting the custom message is correct.  In the code example you posted, the only decorator for that element is `ViewHelper` so the error message will not be displayed.

At the very least, add the `Errors` decorator if you want to see the error message.  Try this:

```
$this->addElement('password', 'code', array(
    'label'      => 'Code',
    'decorators' => array('ViewHelper', 'Errors'),
    'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
    'validators' => array(
        array('Digits', false,
            array('messages' => array('notDigits' => 'Only digits are allowed here')))
    ),
    'required'   => true
);
```

The only change was adding the `Errors` decorator to the stack.

Comment: Thank you for the reply drew010. I am not using Errors decorator, because i am capturing the errors in the controller using $form->getErrors() method, so I could display them in a separate DIV. The errors are displaying correctly, but the translation does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

Try this validator syntax.

```
$this->addElement("text", "fullname", array(
                        'label' => 'Your Full Name: ',
                        'required' => 'true',
                        'validators' => array(
                            array('validator' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array('min'=>5, 'max'=>250, 'messages' => array('stringLengthTooShort' => 'The name is too short.'))) 
                        ),
                        'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
                        'decorators' => array("signup")
                    ));
```